# cobol move statement

Tags: cobol

say i have one 02 level variable as a part of cobybook (testcopy)

```
02 level-1-var
   05 var-1
   05 var-2
   05 var-3
   05 var-4
```

I use this copybook twice in my program.

```
01  usage-1.
    copy testcopy.

01  usage-2.
    copy testcopy.
```

I now want to move **only** 2 level 05 varibale of usage-1 to usage-2.
is there any way i can avoid 2 move statements?

and use something like

```
 MOVE (var-2, var-3) of usage-1   TO 
 (var-2, var-3) of usage-2
```

I am new to cobol and was wondering if this could be done.. this can save a lot of move statements in my program..(improve performance)

Comment: You *have* to move the same amount of data however you do it. Saving on the size of the source code doesn't improve performance at all.

Answer (score 5):

No, not in standard COBOL, although some implementations may well have extensions for that sort of thing. If concise code is one of your requirements, I probably wouldn't have picked COBOL as the ideal language :-)

You probably need to do it in two:

```
move var-2 of usage-1 to var-2 of usage-2.
move var-3 of usage-1 to var-3 of usage-2.
```

If you're willing to do a bit of a change to your copybook, something like <sup>(a)</sup>:

```
02  level-1-var
    05  var-1
    05  var-2-and-3
        09  var-2
        09  var-3
    05  var-4
```

you may find that you can then do it with:

```
move var-2-and-3 of usage-1 to var-2-and-3 of usage-2.
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Obviously, I've just mirrored what you had in the question. You'll almost certainly need `pic` clauses on that data (and probably some more `.` characters).

Answer (score 2):

This type of requirement is directly answered by the MOVE CORRESPONDING verb. MOVE CORRESPONDING takes group levels for its operands and moves like-named elementary items from one to the other, with several restrictions, which include like data classes (i.e., no mixed alphanumeric and numeric). The Fine Manual for your implementation contains all the restrictions.

If I remember correctly, MOVE CORRESPONDING is also an optional feature, so some compilers may not support it.

MOVE CORRESPONDING and your request is one of those things that triggers strong opinions in the COBOL world.  Some say that you should use COPY REPLACING to generate unique data names and code all the MOVEs. Others say what you are doing is fine. My view is that "it depends". If it's a very simple program, I might take the MOVE CORRESPONDING path, but if there is significant business logic, then I would rather code everything.

Comment: The solution you're looking for is a combination of the two answers.  MOVE CORRESPONDING var-2-and-3 OF usage-1 TO var-2-and-3 OF usage-2.  And +1 that MOVE CORRESPONDING is only suitable for a simple one-off program.

Comment: Four years later, thanks to an upvote, I see this comment. :) I'd forgotten about the OF clauses, although I wonder if that's an '85 enhancement and the bulk of my COBOL learning was admittedly with '74.

Comment: @zarchasmpgmr No. OF is present in earlier Cobols.

Comment: Coming back 7½ years later, of course I remember that OF is in the 68 standard.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to make your copybook such that you can have a "prefix" for each field, and then use REPLACING to provide different prefixes for the different COPY statements. Then you don't have to code OF/IN for all the fields, and it will make the program and the listing clearer.

Paxdiablo's is the neatest way to do what you want, although the reason you want to do it would have been interesting.

I'm surprised no-one mentioned "reference modification":

```
MOVE usage-1 ( 3 : 5 ) TO usage-2 ( 3 : 5)
```

Where 3 is the start position in the data and 5 is the length. I much prefer Paxdiablo's defintion to this.

Not so surprised that no-one suggested RENAMES.

```
   01  A-TABLE. 
       05  A-T-1 PIC XX. 
       05  A-T-2 PIC X. 
       05  A-T-3 PIC 9. 
       05  A-T-4 PIC XXX. 
       05  A-T-5 PIC X(4). 
       66 A-TABLE-EXTRA RENAMES A-T-2 THRU A-T-3. 
   01  B-TABLE. 
       05  B-T-1 PIC XX. 
       05  B-T-2 PIC X. 
       05  B-T-3 PIC 9. 
       05  B-T-4 PIC XXX. 
       05  B-T-5 PIC X(4). 
       66 B-TABLE-EXTRA RENAMES B-T-2 THRU B-T-3. 

       MOVE A-TABLE-EXTRA TO B-TABLE-EXTRA
```

Like the MOVE CORRESPONDING, this is to be avoided (same reasons as my comment, plus no-one uses Level 66's, so no-one knows what they do).

Another way is by REDEFINES for each of your Level 01s, but why even go to that bother.